# ¿Cómo modifico una linea de un fichero en Python?

Tags: python, archivo

¿Sabéis si puede abrirse con Python un fichero y que sea a la vez de lectura y escritura?

Necesito modificar un parámetro de un fichero `(line2.split(";")[3])='1'` y consultar después de 5 segundos y en el mismo fichero, otro campo `ValorCambiado = line2.split(";")[6]`.

El fichero tiene el siguiente formato:

```
ALARMA1;0;1;1;4;8;8 (Lo que tengo en origen)
ALARMA2;0;1;1;4;8;8

ALARMA1;0;1;1;4;8;1 (Lo que pretendo conseguir)
ALARMA2;0;1;1;4;8;8
```

Quiero cambiar alguno de los valores de ALARMA1 ó ALARMA2 del fichero pero el resto conservarlo como estaba. Es decir, inyectar un valor concreto a una parte de la línea (En el ejemplo está modificado el `line1.split(";")[6] = 8` (antes) ; `line1.split(";")[6] = 1` (ahora) ). Pero el resto del fichero quedaría igual, y con el mismo nombre de fichero.

¿Esto es posible en Python?

Comment: Te recomiendo que modifiques la pregunta para que pueda ser reabierta. Lo que realmente quieres es modificar parte de una linea de un fichero sin cambiar el resto. Cambia el título a algo asi como ¿Como modifico una linea de un fichero en python? y expllicalo  después como haces en la respuesta de Carles. Realmente tienes que sobreescribir todo el archivo para poder hacer esto, deberas tener en cuenta el tamaño, si es pequeño puedes copiarlo en memoria, modificarlo y luego sobrescribirlo.

Comment: http://es.stackoverflow.com/users/15089/fjsevilla ¿Como hago lo que me comentas? Guardarlo en memoria y sobreescribir, no se como sería....Voy a reformular la pregunta también. Gracias!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si haces ese cambio en **todas** las lineas puedes hacer algo como esto:

```
contenido= list()

with open('fichero.txt', 'r') as archivo:
   for linea in archivo:
       columnas = linea.split(';')
       columnas[6] = '1'
       contenido.append(';'.join(columnas)+'\n')

with open('fichero.txt', 'w') as archivo:
    archivo.writelines(contenido)
```

Si solo lo haces en algunas puedes usar [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) o guardar el documento en una lista usando [`readlines()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/inputoutput.html) y usar el indice para modificar solo aquellas que quieras. Un ejemplo es:

```
def modificar_dato(ruta, filas, columna, nuevo_dato):
    contenido = list()
    with open(ruta, 'r+') as archivo:
        contenido = archivo.readlines()
        for fila in filas:
            columnas = contenido[fila-1].split(';')
            columnas[columna] = nuevo_dato
            contenido[fila-1] = ';'.join(columnas)+ '\n'
    with open(ruta, 'w') as archivo:
        archivo.writelines(contenido)
```

El segundo parámetro de la función es una lista con los nmeros de las filas que quieres modificar, por ejemplo, para modificar la primer , la segunda y la quinta fila la llamas de la siguiente forma:

```
modificar_dato('fichero.txt', [1,2,5], 6, '1')
```

Esto modificara un dichero como este:

```
ALARMA1;0;1;1;4;8;8
ALARMA2;0;1;1;4;8;8
ALARMA3;0;1;1;4;8;8
ALARMA4;0;1;1;4;8;8
ALARMA5;0;1;1;4;8;8
ALARMA6;0;1;1;4;8;8
```

dejandolo así:

```
ALARMA1;0;1;1;4;8;1
ALARMA2;0;1;1;4;8;1
ALARMA3;0;1;1;4;8;8
ALARMA4;0;1;1;4;8;8
ALARMA5;0;1;1;4;8;1
ALARMA6;0;1;1;4;8;8
```

Otra posibilidad es crear un fichero temporal, leer cada linea del original, modificarla y escribirla en el fichero temporal. Al terminar se sustituye el original por el temporal. Esto es más aconsejable si hablamos de ficheros grandes.

La tercera via es usar, como ya te comenté en otra pregunta el módulo [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) ya que estás trabajando con este tipo de ficheros y este módulo facilita bastante las cosas.

Comment: Perfecto. La inyección de datos en fichero ha funcionado correctamente. Por ultimo quedaría pendiente recorrer el fichero viendo que ha cambiado en el fichero de salida tras inyectar un valor. 

Si ALARMA1 pasa de ser ALARMA1;0;1;1;4;8;8 a ser ALARMA1;0;1;1;4;8;9 pues comprobar los cambios en la propia alarma  y en el resto. Para comprobar en sí misma sí que sé como hacerlo pero para mirar si ha cambiado algo en el resto no sabría como mirarlo.

Comment: @AlberM para ver si hay cambios en el archivo solo necesitas una copia de el en memoria como la lista `contenido` de antes o en el disco, abrir el documento de nuevo tras x minutos y ir linea por linea o incluso columna por columna comparando si son iguales. No se exactamente que documento deseas comparar cuando te refieres a `fichero de salida` o que esperas que te retorne si encuentra un cambio. Si sigues con problemas puedes hacer otra pregunta explicandolo bien o incluso hablar por el [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=es.stackoverflow.com) si no merece una pregunta nueva.

Answer (score 3):

Para abrir un fichero en modo Lectura y Escritura a la vez utiliza el indicador `r+` cuando abras el fichero. Ejemplo:

```
with open("fichero.txt", "r+") as fichero:
    fichero.read()
    fichero.write("prueba")
    fichero.close()
```

Comment: Quiero modificar solamente un campo de mi fichero.txt. Me explico....Tengo un fichero.txt y quiero que el campo 4 de cada línea tome valor 1 y el resto lo deje como está.

ALARMA1,0,1,1,2 (Lo que tengo)
ALARMA2,0,1,1,9


ALARMA1,0,1,1,1 (Lo que quiero)
ALARMA2,0,1,1,9

Solo quiero que el campo 4 cambie a valor 1 pero mantener igual el resto del fichero (line1.split(";")[4]) == 1). ¿Esto es posible?